# Java Prime num check not working as expected

Tags: java

i have written the code to check the prime number but its not giving me the correct output

```
 int flag;
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("enter upper nd lower bound");
    int lower = s.nextInt();
    int upper = s.nextInt();
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for (  i =lower ; i<=upper ;i++){
        if(i==1){
        continue;
        }
    }
        flag =1;
         for (  j = 2 ; j<=i/2 ; j++) {
            if(i%j==0)
                flag = 0;
                break;
        }
    if(flag == 1){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

my input is 1  10 
it showing me 11

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your code are not written propperly, it contains error

Comment: @villat my expected ouput is 2 3 5 7 . as these are the prime numbers between 1 to 10

Comment: Looks like a misplaced `}`.  Your first `for` loop takes `i` all the way to 11, before your second loop even starts.  Your second loop should be nested _inside_ the first one, whereas you've got it logically _after_ the first one.

Comment: @Andra If there were no errors in the code, Ajay probably wouldn't have needed to ask a question here.

Comment: Do you mean to break from the loop regardless of whether `i%j==0`? If not, you need to enclose the statements in braces. And if you do, there's no need for it to be a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code was,the second `for loop` should be nested inside the first `for loop`.Because of that the code in second `for loop` was getting `i=11`.When we put the second `for loop` in the nested `for loop` will have the different values of `i` based on the condition.

```
        Boolean flag;
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("enter upper nd lower bound");
        int lower = s.nextInt();
        int upper = s.nextInt();
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        for (  i =lower ; i<=upper ;i++){
            if(i==1){
            continue;
            }
        flag =true;
             for (  j = 2 ; j<=i/2 ; j++) {
                if(i%j==0)
                    flag =false;
                    break;
            }
        if(flag){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Boolean flag;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter upper and lower bound");
        int lower = s.nextInt();
        int upper = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = lower; i <= upper ;i++){
            flag = true;
            if(i <= 1){
                continue;
            }
            flag = true;
            for (int j = 2 ; j<=i/2 ; j++) {
                if(i % j==0) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/iwVrro

Comment: thanx for the solution ... but can u plz help where i was wrong in my code

Comment: @AjayKumarSinha it just the curly bracket `}`, right above the `flag =1;`, you have to move it into the end of code. Also, you only check `i==1` for invalid prime checking, whereas you can't check the primality of any number below 1 right? That's why I change it into `i <= 1`.

Comment: @AjayKumarSinha "Mark as an answer" please?